# Does objectify have a get_or_insert equivalent

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The python version of the datastore has a get_or_insert() method. Does Objectify offer something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Objectify does not have such a feature currently. However, you can implement something similar on your own.

```
public Something getOrInsert(Something s) {    
    return ofy().transact(new Work<Something>() {
        public Something run() {
            Something something = ofy().load().type(Something.class).id(s.getId()).now();
            if(something != null) {
                return something;
            }

            ofy().save().entity(s);

            return s;
        }
    });
}
```